# refactoring a controller query with If/else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is what my index action currently looks like. If the current_user is not enrolled to any courses it lists all courses. If he is enrolled to any, it only lists the other ones. Is this a good way to get the needed records or is there a nicer way? Any suggestions? Thx for your time!

```
if current_user.courses.empty?
  @courses = Course.all
else
  @courses = Course.where("id not in (?)", current_user.courses)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
@user = current_user
@courses = @user.courses.empty? ? Course.all : Course.where("id not in (?)", @user.courses)
```

Comment: Doesn't ActiveRecord::Base#where expect an array of ids as the second argument?

Comment: @user94154 Yeah, I guess it doesn't work with an empty array. Just updated.

Comment: ah its working thx! so is this the short version of if/else in 1 line?

Comment: @DannyRe The `?` is called the ternary operator and is used to simplify assignment based on a boolean value. It exists in most of the more popular programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could move all of this logic into a method on user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def courses
      if self.courses.empty?
         @courses = Course.all
      else
         @courses = Course.where("id not in (?)", current_user.courses)
      end  
   end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@courses = current_user.courses
```

You may also want to re-examine your schema and possibly get rid of the if/else altogether.